# ignite write big data in a pressure test, io write and read time tow high?

Tags: sql, ignite, iowait

I hava some write and find in ignite with sql.When I have a pressure test with 100 persons,  ignite server's cpu is low, but iowait is two heigh, and io write and read time is two heigh. So I have some ways to reduce iowait?
I use 2.7.6 version with two SSD machines as cluster.

this is iowait time picture
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0bka.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyfv1.png
this is iowait cpu picture

Answer (score 0):

In persistent scenarios, you are bound by WAL writes. You can try changing WAL Mode to `LOG_ONLY` to mitigate these peaks slightly.

I recommend making checkpoints further apart (by changing "checkpoint frequency" setting, in `ms`) and maybe increasing "checkpoint page buffer".

Comment: Do you know good idea to improve WAL writes very much?

Comment: LOG_ONLY is default model，I don't change.

Comment: Then, I recommend making checkpoints further apart (by changing checkpoint frequency setting, in `ms`) and maybe increasing checkpoint page buffer.